# Problema multicheckboxes en android studio java para guardar y obtener preferencias de usuario

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

grupo, les solicito ayuda para encontrar una solución al problema que tengo:
contexto: Quiero recorrer un arreglo donde tengo checkboxes obteniendo su id del layout... eso está bien...
mi inconveniente en el código de abajo, es que quiero obtener el valor de cada uno de los muchos checkboxes que tengo declarados en la app, y los cuales están en las shared preferences, debugueando encuentro que si obtengo cada valor de los checks, pero su clave de check que debería de ir c1, c2, c3, no cambia y siempre se queda en c1 , y cambia todos los valores hasta que llega al ultimo, y es el que sí carga la preferencia...
espero haberme dado a entender...
lo que sucede al debuguear es que siempre se queda en c1, y no incrementa la e de mi for a 2, y por ende , no obtiene c2, c3, etc en los checks.

alguna solución? el código donde se presenta el problema está abajo.
les dejaré también el gist para mejor visibilidad... en el gist también viene el metodo mostrar_estado...

gist: https://gist.github.com/.../c9632e255b2f86e5387a8308908020d0

```java
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( "Estado" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//Metodo de recorrido automatico para cargar los estados de los checkbox
String id_sharedcheck = ""; //String para guardar recorrido automatico para la referencia de clave para Sharedpreferences
String id_check = ""; //Almacena el id autoincrementable para los checkbox
for (int e = 1; e <= 5; ++e) {
    id_sharedcheck = "c"+ e;//autoincrementa el nombre clave para el SharedPreferences
    id_check = String.valueOf (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(id_sharedcheck, false)); //Obtiene el estado de checkbox, Autoincrementa el id para los checkbox
    String[] arrCb = id_check.split(" "); //Arreglo que almacene los estados separados por ","
    for (int i = 0; i < arrCb.length; ++i) {
        chboxes [i].setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(arrCb[i]));
    }
    mostrar_estado(id_check);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Felix, estoy tratando de entender tu problema. Queria visitar a la pagina de gist pero el destino resulto con error de 404 pagina no encontrado. Podrias arreglar el link?

Comment: Te lo voy a pedir que compartas la parte del codigo donde almacenas los estados de checkboxes al sharedpreferences para una mayor inspeccion.